# Handling dependent processes in Bash

Tags: macos, bash, redis, zsh

I have a long-running command (`sidekiq`, if you must know) that depends on another long-running processes (`redis-server`, as you may have guessed from the previous parenthetical).

I'd like to write a Bash (well, okay, Zsh actually) alias to start `redis-server` in the background, then run `sidekiq` and, when I use `ctrl-C` to interrupt `sidekiq`, to kill the background Redis job. If it's relevant, I'm on a Mac and only need to support OS X.

So what I'm looking for is something like:

`redis-server & ; sidekiq ; kill $!`

Unfortunately, my interrupt of the `sidekiq` command also prevents the `kill` from occurring. Is there any way to do this?

Bonus points if this can be a one-liner alias and not a function. Double bonus points if I don't have to write to any files in advance (like turning on the `daemonize` flag in `/usr/local/etc/redis.conf`).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe this:

```
#!/bin/zsh
redis-server &
redispid=$!
trap 'kill $redispid' INT
sidekiq
```

Comment: +1 I'd make it a function instead of a script, to more closely match the request for an alias.

Comment: I'm not sure how well `trap` will work in a function, since it's not running in its own process.

Comment: Hm, good point. I was going to say make the body of the function a subshell, but that may not be that different from a script.

Comment: For an alias I can just do `alias sidekiqer="redis-server & ; redispid=$! ; trap 'kill $redispid' INT ; sidekiq"`

Thanks so much!

Comment: Make sure you use single quotes, so `$!` won't be expanded until the alias is used. Your way will expand it when you define the alias.

Comment: But the problem with this is that the `trap` setting will stick around for the rest of your login session, because the alias is in your login shell. That's why you should run it in a subshell.